# How to set "report inappropriate content" with cloudkit?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm learning iOS and am unsure what approach to take here so this isn't specific as I'd like. My app allows users to generate content. I'd like to allow them to flag content that's generated by others as inappropriate. If I'm using cloudkit, do I just create a flag button that sets YES if flagged and in the dashboard search for it? Is there a mechanism I should use in iOS that will notify me of this automatically? Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could indeed add a value that marks a record as inappropriate. You could create a second app (OS X or iOS) that connects to the same data container. In that second app you could create a subscription where the predicate is a filter for that value. You would then receive push notifications whenever something is set to inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks Edwin, this gives me something to investigate further!